# BigInt won't convert to proper date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

So I have a query I'm trying to write where there are two columns that will have variable results. One is date and one is time. My query will look like

```
Select Schedule ID , Job_Name , next_run_date , next_run_time
```

The values will vary depending on what database I'm running against. For example, [next_run_date] might = 20181014 and [next_run_time] might read 1000 which would be 1am. But if I run it on a different server, it could have a completely different set of values, but just the same format.

I've unsuccessfully tried to convert the columns to date/time format by using

```
CONVERT(varchar(10),CONVERT(date,[next_run_date],110),110) AS 'Next Run'
```

And just get '**Explicit conversion from data type int to date is not allowed**'

What I'd like it to display is `[next_run_date] might = 10-14-2018` and `[next_run_time] = 01:00`. Just unsure how to convert this correctly. I **do not** have to write `privs` to the database. If I read correctly, at least for the date column, I would have to convert from `Bigin` to `Varchar` to `ToDate`, but unclear how to fully write that.

Comment: "1000 which would be 1am" did you mean 0100?

Comment: actually I was incorrect, its 10000 is how the value is being displayed. but if I go and look at the scheduled start time of the job in question, it shows Every Sunday 1:00am, so that's where 1am is coming from. I was speaking strictly from preference in that I'd like the value to return in 24hr format.

Comment: Your `CONVERT` line of code returns the expected result for the sample data point in the question. Have you inspected the data in the table to see if there's a value or values that don't fit the YYYYMMDD model? Does `SELECT TOP 5 [next_run_date] DESC` give you anything wonky?

Comment: Since there are many scheduled jobs in this one table, if I look at them all its just more of the same format, but numerous values. I'm starting to blame the architect of this db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the time field you can stuff a `:` in it.
And a FORMAT for the times below 10 AM.

And the date part can be done with 2 casts and a [CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql) or a [FORMAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql).

The date from an INT to a VARCHAR in the 'mm-dd-yyyy' format:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(CAST([next_run_date] AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), 110)
```

The time from an INT to a VARCHAR in the 'hh:mi' format:

```
STUFF(CAST(FORMAT([next_run_time],'000000') AS VARCHAR(4)),3,0,':')
```

**Example snippet:**

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE  (next_run_date INT, next_run_time INT);

INSERT INTO @Table (next_run_date, next_run_time) VALUES 
 (20180901,  13500)
,(20181015, 134200)
;

SELECT 
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST(CAST([next_run_date] AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), 110) AS [Next Run Date],
STUFF(CAST(FORMAT([next_run_time],'000000') AS VARCHAR(4)),3,0,':') AS [Next Run Time]
FROM @Table
```

**Returns:**

```
Next Run Date   Next Run Time
-------------   -------------
09-01-2018              01:35
10-15-2018              13:42
```

Comment: That did it. I had to tweek on the run_time to get it to display 13:00, but that gave me 95% what I needed. Thank you..........

Comment: @Doctorj77 Thanks for the rep. Btw, if this is for some report? Sometimes it's better to just cast them to a DATE or TIME type. And then let the formatting be handled on the front-end.  For the date stamp that's easy, just don't cast the date to a varchar. And the time part can be casted to a TIME type.  Btw, there exists also a [TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) function that would return NULL if the conversion fails (instead of giving an error).

Comment: @Doctorj77 I had to tweak the calculation for the time a bit. Because I realized that with an INT or BIGINT there's no preceding zero under 1000.

Answer (score 0):

select convert(datetime, cast(20181014 as varchar), 102)

Note :

> CAST is part of the ANSI-SQL specification; whereas, CONVERT is not.
>   In fact, CONVERT is SQL implementation specific. CONVERT differences
>   lie in that it accepts an optional style parameter which is used for
>   formatting.

Comment: so if I understand this correctly, that just casts on a particular date. (20181014)... Problem I have is there are more jobs all with different dates in same table, all just happen to be the same format. So I'm trying to figure out the format specifically as the dates will vary

Comment: Just replace the date with the column name in your query. That was an example and to show that it works.

Comment: Gotcha, no I actually did that. Sorry I should have clarified. But it still returns same (2018-10-14 00:00:00.000) regardless of which code I use.

Comment: So you want the time added in as well?

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the bigint to a varchar first, then to a date:

```
CONVERT(date,CONVERT(varchar(10),[next_run_date]),110) AS 'Next Run'
```

Comment: That just put dashes between. Went from 20181014 to 2018-10-14. I've tried changing the code range from 100-110 and it just displays 2018-10-14 each time.

Comment: You wanted to convert a bigint to a date. If you want to disply that date as a varchar in a specific format you must `convert` it again

Answer (score 0):

You could also break up the number into parts and craft a date and time.

```
DECLARE @Date INT=20181014
DECLARE @Time INT=123456

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Date),1,4)+'/'+
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Date),5,2)+'/'+
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Date),7,2)
) AS [Date]

SELECT CONVERT(TIME,
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time),1,LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time))-4)+':'+
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time))-3,2)+':'+
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time),LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),@Time))-1,2)
) AS [Time]
```